# Как создать в css Круг с border-radius: 50% внутри?(делаю это через :hover)

Tags: css, hover, border

[image: bdrs]

Как , используя css, создать внутри круглый бордер?

Пробовал через `outline`, но в нем это невозможно. Так же задавал `border: 1px solid #цвет`, но он ложится естественно на границу, а нужно внутри. Делаю это через `:hover`, то есть при наведении должен появляться круг.

Как используя css реализовть это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, через псевдоэлемент:

```css
body { background-color: black; }

div {
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div:hover::before { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Или через `box-shadow`:

```css
body { background-color: black; }

div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #fff;
}

div:hover { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Или так (наверное лучший из вариантов):

```css
body { background-color: black; }

div {
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

div:hover { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red; }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, что за браузер? Наводить на круг пробовали?

Comment: сорри .. на `hover` сделано ... :)) я удалю комментарий

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, да ладно, комментарий как комментарий xDD

Answer (score 1):

И я свои пять копеек вставлю

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, gold 30%, green 50%, blue 20%);
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.item:hover:before {
  content: "";
  width: 180px;
  padding-top: 180px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="content">
    item1
  </div>
</div>
```